# Which is the preferred coding style in Java?

Tags: java

## #1:

```
proc(Collections.singleton(o));
proc(list);

public void proc(Collection<Object> collection) {
    // pre
    for (Object o : collection) {
        // main
    }
    // post
}
```

- fewer lines
- simplicity
- wrapping is the client task
- slightly slower* (at least 2 object creation: SingletonSet, Iterator)

* maybe it's not a big deal, but what if the method is often used with single value

## #2:

```
proc(o);
proc(list);

public void proc(Object o) {
    // pre
    // main
    // post
}

public void proc(Collection<Object> collection) {
    // pre
    for (Object o : collection) {
        // main
    }
    // post
}
```

- more lines
- complex (may be necessary additional methods to avoid code duplication)
- no need wrapping
- use of overloading
- faster

Or similar problem: (array and list parameter) vs. (only list parameter and use Arrays.asList)

Any suggestions?

Comment: #3: `public void proc(Object o){proc(Collections.singleton(o);}`

Comment: Depends on ``proc``. What is proc? Is it suppose to do stuff on a ``Collection``? For instance ``sum(Collection<Integer> ints)`` makes sense while ``sum(int i)`` makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should expose useful things to the consumers of a service / API. If it is reasonable for the method to be called with a single object and it happens often, you should provide that method.

That being said, you should avoid repeating yourself. The following would be my suggestion:

```
proc(o);
proc(list);

public void proc(Object o) {
    proc(Collections.singleton(o));
}

public void proc(Collection<Object> collection) {
    // pre
    for (Object o : collection) {
        // main
    }
    // post
}
```

Worrying about the optimization of `Collections.singleton` is not worthwhile here

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are building something for your internal use, create the methods as you need them. No need to write an overload for array parameters if it is never called
2. If you are building an API to be shared within your institution, follow the practices already defined. There should be coworkers/architects/managers to discuss this with, not SO.
3. If you are building an API for the general public, take input from your bug tracker/mailing list/forums. What are users asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i think i never saw #1.

Even in the jdk, you'll see plenty of overloaded methods that does the same thing, but receives different kind of parameters.

You should always make it easy for the user of your class to find the right method, instead of forcing him to do some acrobatics to be able to call your methods.

But that's only my opinion, code style is always discutable.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on **what** proc is doing, on **what** it is supposed to receive as an argument.

For instance if `proc` is the `sum` function, then `sum(Collection<Integer> ints)` makes complete sense while `sum(int i)` makes no sense at all and should not be provided as a function.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to keep API as simple as possible. So better do many overloaded versions of the same method, rather than user will have to convert or wrap parameters.
Java code conventions can be useful, here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf